# Where is the error in this Java code?

Tags: java, jframe, windowbuilder

I am trying to use window builder to code this simple task, however, eclipse always says its wrong and doesn't execute. Please what is the mistake on this code? *all the packages are imported. Hello, I am trying to use window builder to code this simple task, however, eclipse always says its wrong and doesn't execute. Please what is the mistake on this code? *all the packages are imported.

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField nota_periodo1;
private JTextField nota_periodo2;
private JTextField nota_periodo3;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Ventana1 frame = new Ventana1();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 * @return 
 */


public Ventana1() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(176, 224, 230));
    contentPane.setForeground(new Color(176, 224, 230));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblCalculadoraDeNotas = new JLabel("CALCULADORA DE NOTAS SGS");
    lblCalculadoraDeNotas.setBounds(146, 20, 200, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblCalculadoraDeNotas);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Nota Periodo I:");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(20, 60, 104, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    nota_periodo1 = new JTextField();
    nota_periodo1.setBounds(118, 55, 130, 26);
    contentPane.add(nota_periodo1);
    nota_periodo1.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Nota Periodo 2:");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(20, 88, 104, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JLabel lblNotaPeriodo = new JLabel("Nota Periodo 3:");
    lblNotaPeriodo.setBounds(20, 113, 104, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblNotaPeriodo);

    nota_periodo2 = new JTextField();
    nota_periodo2.setBounds(128, 83, 130, 26);
    contentPane.add(nota_periodo2);
    nota_periodo2.setColumns(10);

    nota_periodo3 = new JTextField();
    nota_periodo3.setBounds(118, 108, 130, 26);
    contentPane.add(nota_periodo3);
    nota_periodo3.setColumns(10);

    // OBJETO DE INICIO
    Ventana1 start = new Ventana1();
    String principio = start.Inicio();

    JButton calcular = new JButton("Calcular");
    calcular.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(principio);
        }
    });
    calcular.setBounds(40, 159, 104, 29);
    contentPane.add(calcular);

    JLabel lblUstedTieneQue = new JLabel("Usted Tiene que Sacar: ");
    lblUstedTieneQue.setBounds(23, 200, 157, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblUstedTieneQue);

    JLabel nota_examen_final = new JLabel("");
    nota_examen_final.setBounds(172, 200, 61, 16);
    contentPane.add(nota_examen_final);

    JLabel lblEnElExamen = new JLabel("en el Examen Final");
    lblEnElExamen.setBounds(245, 200, 124, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblEnElExamen);


    }

//METODO INICIO
public String Inicio (){
    int nota1 = Integer.parseInt(nota_periodo1.getText());
    int nota2 = Integer.parseInt(nota_periodo2.getText());
    int nota3 = Integer.parseInt(nota_periodo3.getText());
    double nota1p = nota1*0.35;
    double nota2p = nota2*0.25;
    double nota3p = nota3*0.2;
    double notapass = 60-(nota1p+nota2p+nota3p);
    double notaex = notapass/0.2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, notaex);
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours. The code is missing the import statements and there's no evidence what "eclipse always says its wrong" is.

Comment: More information is better than just copying your small bit of text over and over to get around the content requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You should have posted the stack trace, which shows what is wrong:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:45)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
    at test.Ventana1.<init>(Ventana1.java:87)
```

The problem is this line in your constructor for `Ventana1`:

```
// OBJETO DE INICIO
Ventana1 start = new Ventana1();
```

This will create a new `Ventana1` when a new `Ventana1` is created.

Comment: Upvote for bothering to help the OP when they weren’t exactly helping themselves.

Comment: Yeah, that sure looks like it'll cause an exception.

Comment: I thought about posting this text twice in the same answer. But then I looked at the stacktrace...

Answer (score 0):

Please declare all your methods inside a **class**.

```
public class MyClass { }
```

Your main method and other methods seems to be outside the class declaration.

Comment: Please post this as a comment, not as answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to declare Ventana1 as public class, not just public. Also the way it is written it seems you were after a function, not a class.

Also, inside Ventana1 you do this:

```
Ventana1 start = new Ventana1();
String principio = start.Inicio();
```

This seem to be creating an object of itself, although its not a class. Also I believe object creation is usually done outside the class of the object.

Finally, the function Inicio() is not part of the Ventana1 class, so cannot be called here.